# How to shift y axis in plotly?

Tags: plotly, documentation, axis

The link above shows a different graph, when plotted, as the example shows on the site.
https://plotly.com/python/multiple-axes/#shift-axes-by-a-specific-number-of-pixels
Why is this?
The shift parameter itself is not changing the position of the axis.
I know this can be solved with position, but that is relative to the plot width.

Comment: I ran it in my environment and got the same results as the reference. My environment is the latest version, 5.15.0.